# The inversion of the Laplacian transform Pazy's Book "semigroups of linear operators and applications to Partial differential equations"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-of-operators

This question [has been posted on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4529906/228959) but no reply, and so I have to put it here. My question is:

In Pazy's Book page 26, the author gives a proof of Lemma 7.1, the lemma 7.1 says that: Let $B$ be a bounded linear operator. If $\gamma>\|B\|$ then $$e^{tB}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}e^{\gamma t}R(\lambda;B)d\lambda$$ The convergence in this formula is in the uniform operator topology and **uniformly in t on bounded intervals**.

In the proof of this lemma, the author get $$e^{tB}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_{r}}e^{\lambda t}R(\lambda;B)d\lambda$$ where $C_{r}$ be the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Choose $r$ such that $\gamma>r>\|B\|$.

Then the author says that since outside $C_{r}$ the integral of the above formula is analytic and $\|R(\lambda;B)\|\leq C|\lambda|^{-1}$ **we can shift the path of integral from $C_{r}$ to the line $Re z=\gamma$, using Cauchy's theorem**.

I can just prove this is right when $t\in [\alpha,\beta]$ in which $0<\alpha<\infty,0<\beta<\infty$, that is to say, I can just check pazy's proof is right when $t$ in a compact set away from zero, but can not justify whether $t\in [0,T]$ is right. So, How can I check the "$t\in[0,T]$"? How to **shift the path of integral** from $C_{r}$ to the line $Re z=\gamma$ when $t\in [0,T],T<\infty$?

Any hints are welcome, Thank you very much!!

Comment: I agree that this point is not well explained in the book. Letting $t=0$ gives problems for the convergence since one cannot use Jordan lemma in the left half-plane. One can avoid the problem by subtracting $I$, writtten as the integral over the vertical line of $e^{\lambda t}/\lambda$

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for your correction!!!! I learn a lot from your correction!

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune But in Pazy's Book, He applied the "wrong" theorem7.1 to theorem 7.4, which puzzled me long time. I don't know whether the author used theorem 7.4 in latter theorems, if so, the book by Pazy will be unsuitable for me.

Comment: I agree that the convergence cannot be uniform in $[0,T]$ since the integral on the vertical line for $t=0$ does not converge (here one has to subtract $I$, written as in my previous comment). In Theorem 7.4 integrate from $\epsilon$ to T in formula (7.13) where you have uniform convergence so that you can let $k \to \infty$. Then let $\epsilon \to 0$, to get  (7.15), using the strong continuity on the LHS and dominated convergence for the term containing $e^{\lambda \epsilon}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much!!!!! I get your idea. Best Wishes!!!